# Argument that two given finite groups are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Two finite groups are to be compared in terms of structure (whether isomorphic or not):
$\langle \, x,y \mid x^2,\ y^2,\ (xy)^2 \, \rangle$ 
and
$\langle \, x,y \mid x^4,\ y^2 = x^2,\ yxy^{-1} = x^{-1} \, \rangle$.

First group is very simple, the second one not so much. However I found both of them on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group#Examples) - their orders are 4 and 8 respectively.

So for the second group do I still have to figure out all the relations (to arrive at order 8) just to make a statement that orders are not equal hence no isomorphism? Is there a quick formal argument for example that order is greater than 4?

Comment: You could use the relations to explicitly write down a group multiplication table, taking $x^iy^j$, $0\le i\le 3, 0\le j\le 1$ as group elements.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Assuming I didn't know the group beforehand apparently I'd have to take $\{ x,y \}^k$ as group elements (for $k=0,1,\ldots$)?

Comment: The relation $x^4$ says you need no power of $x$ greater than 3; $y^2$, no power of $y$ greater than 1; $yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}$ can be written $yx=x^3y$ which tells you that you can move any $y$ that's to the left of an $x$ to the right of that $x$. That's how you get to what @Hagen has written.

Comment: These types of problems are very hard. A group that is finitely presented need not be finite even if the generators have finite order: consider $\langle x,y \mid x^3 = y^3 = (xy)^3 =1 \rangle $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That presentation is recognized as the presentation of a Dicyclic group.
For reference, the dicyclic group of degree $n$ is given by
$$
\mathrm{Dic}_n
=
\langle
a, x
\mid
a^{2n} = 1,\ x^2=a^n,\ xax^{-1}=a^{-1}
\rangle
$$
and has order $4n$. Your group is just $\mathrm{Dic}_2$ and so has order 8. By the way,
$\mathrm{Dic}_2 \cong Q_8$, the quaternion group.